# Digit/Number Recognition Hand-written

Tags: c++, gesture-recognition

Can anyone recommend a handwritten digit/number recognition library which I could use in c++/OpenGL. I need to recognise the digits/numbers in my OpenGL project written by a user.

Comment: OpenGL has nothing to do with recognition. It is a rendering system; it *draws* stuff.

Comment: the interface to draw the digits on is written by OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), you should be fine if you're only working with digits.